# Dynamically building LINQ query using OR operator in VB

Tags: vb.net, linq, predicate

I need to build a dynamic linq query with or operators.  I have seen PredicateBuilder but that is in C# and my project is in VB.  Basically I need to build a WHERE clause similar to this:

```
Where((this = 1 AND that = 2) OR (this = 1 AND that = 4) OR (this = 2 AND that = 4))
```

but the problem is the number will have to be determined dynamically at runtime, and added using a loop, like

```
for each item in myItems
    query = query.OR (this = item.a AND this = item.b)
next
```

How could I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the LinqKit.dll working, now using PredicateBuilder even with my VB project and it works very well!

For anyone else needing this see http://rocksthoughts.com/blog/archive/2008/04/10/linq-to-sql-dynamic-queries-3-ands--ors-together.aspx, very good article on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [LINQ Dynamic Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)?

Comment: yeah I was aware of that but I didn't think it met my needs really, I'd have to dynamically build the sql using concatenation which is highly unwanted by my client.  I actually just got linqkit and predicatebuilder working!